# When I run SikuliX IDE SikuliX starts but gets stuck with this pop up on screen: "SikuliX-IDE 2.0.4 is starting on Java 11"

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I am new with Sikuli. When I run SikuliX IDE SikuliX starts but gets stuck with this pop up on screen: "SikuliX-IDE 2.0.4 is starting on Java 11". How can I solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After that it should open your IDE, if not, try uninstalling java 11 and  installing java 8. Should work after that